# SQL Server select and set in a single insert statement

Tags: sql-server

Can I increment and also use a variable in a single insert statement? What I am looking after is: I am generating inserts for a table from a CSV, but I would also need a unique value for the table (the target table has no identity/sequence PKs, only a single, `nvarchar(50)` PK)

```
DECLARE @counter INT = 1;

INSERT INTO table ([Code],[Name]) VALUES( @counter = @counter + 1, 'val 1');
INSERT INTO table ([Code],[Name]) VALUES( @counter = @counter + 1, 'val 2');
INSERT INTO table ([Code],[Name]) VALUES( @counter = @counter + 1, 'val 3');
```

This does not work, but anything similar? (I would need to CAST the `@counter` to `nvarchar` in the end, but does not matter for the solution)

Comment: Hi - Have you tried "set counter = counter + 1" after each insert statement?

Comment: You can also take a look at [`INDENTITY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property) and [`SEQUENCE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not increasing the `@counter` variable

```
INSERT INTO table ([Code],[Name]) VALUES( @counter, 'val 1');
set @counter = @counter + 1
INSERT INTO table ([Code],[Name]) VALUES( @counter, 'val 2');
set @counter = @counter + 1
INSERT INTO table ([Code],[Name]) VALUES( @counter, 'val 3');
```

Also, I suggest you to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to handle identity properly;

```
select @counter = MAX(Code) from table

INSERT INTO table ([Code],[Name]) VALUES( @counter, 'val 1');
select @counter = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO table ([Code],[Name]) VALUES( @counter, 'val 2');
select @counter = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO table ([Code],[Name]) VALUES( @counter, 'val 3');
```

Comment: Hmmmmmm, I guess you win. :D